# A question regarding the state space of a random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

Let's suppose that we are working with a $\text{U(0,1)}$ random variable $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$.

Then we define that $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}$ and the probability density function of $X$ is

$
f_X(x)=\begin{cases}
1, \quad x \in [0,1],\\
0, \quad \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$

Why do we need to define the state space of $X$ to be $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}$. Why can't we define the state space as $\mathcal{X} = [0,1]$ and the density as $f_X(x)= 1, \quad x \in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}$ is just part of the definition of continous random variables (and $X\sim U(0,1)$  is an example of a continous randm variable).

Comment: Yes. But the question is: Why do we need to define the state space as $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}$. In the example we use a density with a support [0,1] and takes value 1 on the support. The value of the density is 0 outside the support. Why can't we just set the state space as $\mathcal{X} = [0,1]$ and define a density that takes value 1 on the interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: @display_name You don't technically need to, but this way you have the nice property that you can do operations on random variables that are defined for real numbers and still get a random variable with the same state space. This is a pretty normal situation for choices of codomain; we don't usually insist on selecting codomains to be equal to ranges.

Comment: @Ian Oh that's right! Thank you very much!